# Why lightning:formattedNumber cuts off digits?

Tags: lightning-web-components

When I tried to display values of record fields using  `lightning:formattedNumber` I have noticed a strange bug.

On Lightning standard interface, all digits are displayed correctly.
On custom page, only three digits are displayed.

Number-Format LWC code (html):

```
<template>
    <lightning-formatted-number value={value}></lightning-formatted-number>
</template>
```

Number-Format LWC code (javascript):

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class NumberFormat extends LightningElement {
    @api value;
}
```

Aura standalone application which uses this component

```
<aura:application >
    <aura:attribute name="val" type="Double" default="23.5467"/>
    <c:numberFormat value="{!v.val}"/>
</aura:application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not straightforward obvious but [documentation states that](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-number/documentation)

> Decimal numbers default to 3 decimal places.

So to fix the code, it is enough to specify `maximum-fraction-digits=21`

```
<template>
    <lightning-formatted-number value={value} maximum-fraction-digits=21></lightning-formatted-number>
</template>
```

Update: in a generic case significant digits should be used, since maximum-fraction-digits doesn't work for percent

```
<template>
    <lightning-formatted-number value={value} maximum-significant-digits=21></lightning-formatted-number>
</template>

<template>
    <lightning-formatted-number format-style="percent" value={value} maximum-significant-digits=21></lightning-formatted-number>
</template>
```

Update: for number it is better to use `maximum-fraction-digits`.
For percent it might be better idea to display row value avoiding using formatting number since when value of maximum-fraction-digits >= 14, it is ignored and zero fraction digits are displayed, and even when maximum-significant-digits is set to 21, the value still is truncated and 21 significant digits are not displayed.